# Linear predictive model: how to attribute performance to individual features?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, model-evaluation

Here is my use case:

I am running some data analysis for a large retail chain who has thousands of outlets across the country. I am using a linear predictive model to predict whether we should start a market campain for a specific outlet, e.g., 10% discount for all products in the outlet on a Sunday. The compain could lead to either a boost of profit or a damage of profit.

I have a around 20 'features' and around 5000 training samples (in-sample). I used logicstic regression to make prediction, if the prediction value is higher than a threshold then we will initiate the discount marketing campain.

So far the model works ok and we had a few thousands of real-world samples (out of sample). In total we had boosted the profit by $M$ dollars.

So far what I have done is to analyze the out-of-sample correlation betwen each feature and  compain's revenue impact. However, I am wondering if there is a way that I can **quantitatively** attribute the M dollars to the 20 'features'. Something like: feature #2 (regional google Ad click count) contributed 500K among the $M$ dollars. feature #15 (regional Uber traffic) contributed -20K among the $M$ dollars.

The tricky part is that , the attribution is not necessarily positive. A feature might have negative contribution to the total profit.

Also, I cannot come out with a definition of 'fairness' when we evaluate the attribution. For example, if feature #2 shows every strong OOS correlation with result, and I attribute all the $M$ dollars to #2. My intuition says this is 'unfair'. But I don't know how to define that.

Can anyone share any insights here?

Comment: I’m wondering if it will be (much) easier to start tackling this in the linear regression case and then get to what happens when there’s a link function. Cool question, though, +1.